# how to insert multiple values in a single text field using autocomplete function in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I want to populate a text field using Drupal which allows multiple values using a "," as a separator. I wish to implement this functionality using autocomplete function of drupal...

Eg: if in a text field I enter "J", it gives me several options starting with the letter "J" due to the autocomplete feature.
     After selecting that particular value, I type a "," and again press a keyboard key eg "A". Now it should give me all the available values starting with "A".

How can I accomplish it?

Thank you